# view will not load by function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using codeigniter 3 built a function to view a blog post by the slug, to show the full text from the thumbnail image.

Everything I click on the blog post I get a 404 error, I have checked my routes,spelling,and table and still get the same error.

The slug is made from the url_title function.

I have ran out of ideas.

route: ( I have moved it from the top to bottom)

```
$route['Content/(:any)'] = 'Content/blogview/$1';
```

function:(removed the 404 also still same issue)

```
public function blogview($slug=NULL) {
    $data['Bpost'] = $this->Blog_Model->get_bposts($slug);

    if(empty($data['Bposts'])){
        show_404();
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('blogfull',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_bposts($slug = FALSE) {
    if($slug === FALSE){
        $this->db->order_by('date','DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('blogposts');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('blogposts',array('slug'=>$slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

This is my htaccess if needed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I am going to guess that its going to be a route issue. I have the same functions on another website and they work great. I really ran out of ideas on what it could be.

Blogging Function to show one post in the table that loads the thumbnail post I use a foreach() to loop through them.

```
public function blogging() {
    $data['Bposts'] = $this->Blog_Model->get_bposts();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('blogging',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Updating with more information:

These are all my routes:

```
$route['Content/blogging'] = 'Content/blogging';
$route['Content/bloggingposts'] = 'Content/bloggingposts';
$route['Content/(:any)'] = 'Content/blogview/$1';

$route['Content/mail'] = 'Content/mail';

$route['Content/signed'] = 'Content/signed';

$route['Content/contactme'] = 'Content/contactme';
$route['Content/contact'] = 'Content/contact';

$route['Content/adminview']='Content/adminview';
$route['Content/blogpost']='Content/blogpost';

$route['Content/(:any)'] = 'Content/fullview/$1';
```

All the blog functions in the controller:

```
public function blogging(){

    $data['Bposts'] = $this->Blog_Model->get_bposts();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('blogging',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function blogview($slug=NULL) {
$data = array();
    $data['Bpost'] = $this->Blog_Model->get_bposts($slug);


    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $data['view'] = 'blogfull';
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function bloggingposts(){

$data['title']= "Admin Area";

$title=$this->input->post('title');

$slug = url_title($title, 'dash', true);

$this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title',array('required', 'min_length[1]'));

if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('adminblogging',$data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {

            $image = "";

            if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != "")
            {
                 if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
                    $ext = ".jpeg";
                } else if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/png'){
                    $ext = ".png";
                }

                $image = time();

                                $config = array(
                                    'file_name' => $image,
                                    'upload_path' => "assets/blogimg/",
                                    'allowed_types' => "jpg|png|jpeg",
                                );

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){

                            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error_msg', $this->upload->display_errors());
                                     redirect('Content/adminview');
                                 }

                                 else {

                    $this->Blog_Model->bposting($image,$slug);
                    $image = "assets/blogimg/".$image;

                }
            } else {
                $this->Blog_Model->bposting($image,$slug);
            }


        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created','Your Post has been submitted');
        redirect('Content/blogging');
    }
}
```

Models for blog functions:

```
public function get_bposts($slug = FALSE){


if($slug === FALSE){
  $this->db->order_by('date','DESC');
  $query = $this->db->get('blogposts');
  return $query->result_array();
}

$query = $this->db->get_where('blogposts',array('slug'=>$slug));
return $query->row_array();


}

public function bposting($image,$slug){


  $data = array(
    'slug'=>$slug,
    'the_image' => $image,
    'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
    'body'=> $this->input->post('body'),

);

return $this->db->insert('blogposts',$data);
}
```

Comment: what is the result of this `print_r($data['Bpost'])`?

Comment: it shows the array of the one post i have in the table that is loaded by this one function called blogging that I updated in my original post

Comment: function executing the body of `if()` statement?

Comment: if(empty($data['Bposts'])){ }   Here $data['Bposts'] key is wrong. Please change to $data['Bpost']   it seems that, you are adding "S"  extra in last.

Comment: You have a typo. You define `$data['Bpost']` but are checking `$data['Bposts']` in your `if`-statement. Those are two different keys, which means that the `if`-statement will always evaluate true and show the 404 page instead of the view.

Comment: Nope I deleted the function it still does not work, I just added the function back  and edited it and still am receiving the 404 error. its loading the view like http://localhost/main/Content/top-post

Comment: _"Nope I deleted the function"_ - What are you saying "no" to? In the above code, there _is_ a typo that would result in 404. Also, what "function" did you remove?

Comment: I corrected the typo from Bposts to Bpost and I still have the error. I than removed the if statement altogether and I still have this 404 error that persist.

Comment: Please write only echo "hi"; and remove all the code in that function only. and check

Comment: Okay just did it, when I go to load the function I get a 404, that is just with the echo "hi" so if I go into routes and add $route['Content/blogview'] = 'Content/blogview/'; than it works as expected. Is my route incorrect in the other way?

Comment: I used same function and routes as per your questions. But it is working on my side.

Comment: Did you add __construct method? If yes, please share a code.

Comment: Updated my post with more information. As you will see I have two similar routes.

Comment: Just another update when I delete the one similar route $route['Content/(:any)'] = 'Content/fullview/$1'; and keep the blogview one it works, but I need both... So its something with the routes than

Comment: as per your updated code, $route['Content/(:any)'] = 'Content/blogview/$1';

$route['Content/(:any)'] = 'Content/fullview/$1';   are override and execute last one rules.

Comment: If you want to use same rules for different method, it is not possible but you can add $route['Content/v/(:any)']='Content/blogview/$1'  so, it is working fine.

Comment: So what is the work around for this, if I needed to use two different methods? Also thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you want to use two different methods then you need to add some prefix in URL as I said in previous comments. e.g,...  for delete=> d,....for view=>v etc...
$route['Content/v/(:any)']='Content/blogview/$1  // I added v here...

Comment: @DarshakDRC That still never corrected the issue, I even tried putting something before the controller and with and without adding the method also to no luck, I just created a new controller and solved the issue, But I still would like to know the fix for this because sometimes you cannot just create a new controller. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

try this: I hope it will help you

```
public function blogview($slug=NULL) {
$data = array();
    $data['Bpost'] = $this->Blog_Model->get_bposts($slug);

    if(empty($data['Bposts'])){
        show_404();
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $data['view'] = 'blogfull';
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: Still receiving that 404 error. I really do not know what I am missing, this same functions work in another application I made.